# Iterate through object in array and add new property based on Regex match of existing property

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex, object

I'm new to Javascript and would appreciate some help.

I have the following array of objects :

```
var data = [{
 name: 'name1',
 street: 'street2',
 person: 'person1',
 phone1: 'phone82 ',
 phone2: 'phone3'
},
{
 name: 'name2',
 street: 'street2',
 person: 'person1',
 phone1: 'phone1 ',
 phone2: 'phone2'
}]
```

My goal is to iterate through each object, and assign a new property value dynamically, by taking each existing property value, and assign a new property based on a regex that matches an existing property value to make the new property value.

To achieve this, I tried to create the following code, that iterates through each object, declare the Regex expression into a variable, and then match each object property to the regular expression, then subsequently use the map function to add an entry.

The code seems to iterate through each object, but when I attempt to map each property dynamically, it only matches the last value of the property.

```
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
  var parseaddress = new RegExp(/(.*)/);
  var street1 = data[j].street.match(parseaddress)[0]
var parsecity = new RegExp(/(.*)/)
var city = data[j].street.match(parsecity)[0]
var parsepostal = new RegExp(/(.*)/)
var postal = data[j].street.match(parsepostal)

  data.map(function(entry) {
    entry.address = street1
});

  data.map(function(entry) {
    entry.city = city
});

  data.map(function(entry) {
    entry.postalcode = postal
});


}
```

If I log `data[j].street`, I receive all values with key street, in each object, however when I assign the regex expression to each street property and map it, it just matches the last object street value to all other objects.

How can I dynamically assign all values a new property based on a regex match of an existing property?

Comment: where you have declared  `out`

Comment: Whoops, mistake. Let me fix.

Comment: I have created a fiddle, now can you tell what's your expected output: `https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/nrj98f0w/8/`

Comment: array.prototype.map does not modify the original array, but rather returns a new array with the modifed values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map So if you do data = data.map... it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the existing loop, using `map` inside the loop will cause you to overwrite the previous values

```js
  var data = [{ name: 'name1', street: 'street1', person: 'person1', phone1: 'phone82 ', phone2: 'phone3' }, { name: 'name2', street: 'street2', person: 'person1', phone1: 'phone1 ', phone2: 'phone2' }]

   for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
    var parseaddress = new RegExp(/(.*)/g);
    var street1 = data[j].street.match(parseaddress)[0]
  var parsecity = new RegExp(/(.*)/g)
  var city = data[j].street.match(parsecity)[0]
  var parsepostal = new RegExp(/(.*)/g)
  var postal = data[j].street.match(parsepostal)[0]
  
    data[j].address = street1
    data[j].city = city
    data[j].postalcode = postal
  
  }
  console.log(data)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you working well. It seems I mis-used map here. Thank you.